# When some process has a file open, what will unlink() do?

Tags: c, linux, file, hardlink

From APUE

> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
> int unlink(const char *pathname);
> ```
>
> Only  when  the  link  count  reaches  0  can  the  contents  of  the 
>   ﬁle  be  deleted. One other  condition  prevents  the  contents  of  a
>   ﬁle  from  being  deleted:  **as  long  as  some process  has  the  ﬁle 
>   open**,  its  contents  will  not  be  deleted. When  a  ﬁle  is 
>   closed,  the kernel ﬁrst checks the count of the number of processes
>   that have the ﬁle open. If this count has reached 0, the kernel then
>   checks the link count; if it is 0, the ﬁle’s contents are deleted.

1. If a file is being used by `execve()` in a process, does it count it as "the process has the file open"?
2. If some process has the file being open or `execve()`ed, will `unlink()` immediately return 0 or -1, or wait till the process closes the file or `execve()` finishes running and performs its job?

Comment: Remember to account for the O_CLOEXEC flag to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), and the `FD_CLOEXEC` option to
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to an open file handle on Linux if the pointed file gets moved, delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-del)

Comment: A process is a process. In what way doesn't your quotation answer your question entirely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The file handles inherited by processes via `execve` will remain open until explicitly closed or the process exits.

2) `unlink` will not block. It will simply remove the path and decrement the reference count of the hard-linked file, at which point the filesystem may remove the referenced file and free the space associated with it once the file is no longer opened by any process. `unlink` will return 0 unless there was an I/O or permissions error, etc.

Comment: Thanks. "The file handles inherited by processes via execve ", but `execve()` unlike `open()` doesn't return a file handle

Comment: The spawned process inherits the file handle table of the original process.

Comment: But `execve()` doesn't return a file handle

Comment: On success, `execve` does *not* return. The currently executing program is replaced with a new one.

Answer (score 3):

For a file which is [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-d or [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed, the kernel also considers that (inside the kernel) the file descriptor is used (so the kernel inode has a refcount which is positive). See also [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Notice the `ETXTBSY` error code in [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). An executable could even remove itself during execution (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18165490/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009791/841108)) and the file's inode remains until the process is terminated or does some other `execve`.

Hence the data inside such as file is not released (until the `execve` or `mmap` is inactivated)